# How to convert a publisher to a CurrentValueSubject?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

I have a publisher that my view's `onReceive` is subscribed to. Instead of duplicating logic in `onAppear` as well, I'd like the publisher in the `onReceive` to fire on first subscribe.

Is there a way to convert a publisher to a `CurrentValueSubject`? Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var myPublisher: CurrentValueSubject<Void, Never> {
    Just(()) // Error: Cannot convert return expression of type 'Just<()>' to return type 'CurrentValueSubject<Void, Never>'
}
```

Is this possible or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't convert publishers to `CurrentValueSubject` at will because it's a very specific type of publisher. Ask yourself whether you really need the type of `myPublisher` to be `CurrentValueSubject<Void, Never>` or if an `AnyPublisher<Void, Never>` would do.

```
var myPublisher: AnyPublisher <Void, Never> {
    Just(()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Alternatively, if all you're trying to do is create an instance of `CurrentValueSubject` that has `()` as its initial value you could use this:

```
var myPublisher: CurrentValueSubject<Void, Never> {
    CurrentValueSubject<Void, Never>(())
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can assign a publisher to a `CurrentValueSubject` which you can then use in your code. Without duplicating the logic.

```swift
var oldPublisher: AnyPublisher <Void, Never>
    
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
var myCurrentValueSubject: CurrentValueSubject<Void, Never> {
    let subject = CurrentValueSubject<Void, Never>(())
    oldPublisher
      .assign(to: \.value, on: subject)
      .store(in: &cancellables)
    return subject
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't allow you to access the value directly. In SwiftUI, this ASSIGN causes so many problems because it's not updated immediately.